# How to make link to zoom a pic

Tags: jquery, image, zooming

I currently have a great script that works well.

When I click the image, the zoom function works.

But I need to create a separate link to zoom.

Any suggestions.

```
    jQuery.fn.center = function () {
    this.css("position","absolute");
    this.css("top", ( $(window).height() - this.height() ) / 2+$(window).scrollTop() + "px");
    this.css("left", ( $(window).width() - this.width() ) / 2+$(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
    return this;
}

$(document).ready(function() {      
    $("#profile_pict_lifesign img").click(function(e){

        $("#background1").css({"opacity" : "0.7"})
                        .fadeIn("slow");            

        $("#large1").html("<img src='"+$(this).parent().attr("href")+"' alt='"+$(this).attr("alt")+"' /><br/>"+$(this).attr("rel")+"")
                   .center()
                   .fadeIn("slow");         

        return false;
    });

    $(document).keypress(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode==27){
            $("#background1").fadeOut("slow");
            $("#large1").fadeOut("slow");
        }
    });

    $("#background1").click(function(){
        $("#background1").fadeOut("slow");
        $("#large1").fadeOut("slow");
    });

    $("#large1").click(function(){
        $("#background1").fadeOut("slow");
        $("#large1").fadeOut("slow");
    });

});




<div id="profile_pict_lifesign"><img src="pic_memory.jpg" alt="" rel=""><a href="pic_memory.jpg">zoom</a>


                    <div id="profile_specs_wrap">
                            <div id="profile_specs_1">LIFESIGN #203</div>
                            <div id="profile_specs_2">Louis Tharp</div>
                            <div id="profile_specs_3">Born:&nbsp;&nbsp;September 20, 1964</div>
                            <div id="profile_specs_4">Home City & State:&nbsp;&nbsp;Indianapolis, Indiana</div>
                            <div id="profile_specs_5">Homeless Status:&nbsp;&nbsp;"Still Homeless"</div>
                            <div id="profile_specs_6">Homeless  Timer:&nbsp;&nbsp;4 Years, 3 Months, & 4 Days</div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="profile_specs_wrap2">
                    <div id="profile_specs_7">This is a photograph of Louis with his two loving sisters in 1969.</div>

                    </div>

                </div>


                    <div id="large1"></div>
                    <div id="background1"></div>
```

Comment: Try Create new html document, clone jquery, fn.center, image, from open document to new html document, open new html document in new window on click event, call fn.center in window load event callback.

Answer (score 0):

Try (this pattern)

```
$(function () {
    $("img")
    .on("click", function (e) {
        var data = ["<img class=zoom />"];
        $.when(data)
        .done(function (data) {
            var center = function () {
                this.css("position", "absolute");
                this.css("top", ($(window).height() - this.height()) / 2 
                         + $(window).scrollTop() + "px");
                this.css("left", ($(window).width() - this.width()) / 2 
                         + $(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
                return this;
            };
            if ($(data[0]).is(".zoom")) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    var z = window.open("", "z");
                    z.center = center;
                    z.document.write(data[0]);
                    z.document.write("<style>" + $("style").text() + "</style>");
                    z.document.write("<scr" 
                     + "ipt>"
                     + "(function() { var script=document.createElement('script');" 
                     + " script.src = 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js';"
                     + "var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];" 
                     + "head.appendChild(script)})()</scr" 
                     + "ipt>");
                    // do stuff in new window
                    z.document.write("<scr" 
                      + "ipt>(function()" 
                      + "{ setTimeout(function() {" 
                      + "if (window.jQuery) {" 
                      + " jQuery.fn.center = window.center;" 
                      + "jQuery('.zoom').center()}},50)}())</scr" 
                      + "ipt>");
                }, 250);
            };
        });
    });
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/aBDRD/